# Shell Script to Create Blank File in Working Directory (Mac OS X)

Tags: macos, shell, sh

I want to write a shell script that you can drop anywhere and when you open it, it simply creates a new file in that directory. So far I have this:

```
#!/bin/bash
BASEDIR=$(dirname $0)
touch $BASEDIR/untitled
```

Which works, except there's two things I'd like to do to it that I have no idea how to.

1. Is there a way to get Finder to focus on it after creating it? (like how Windows and most Linux distros do when you do Create New File from the right click context menu)
2. How can I make the script not open terminal each time you click on it? Would I need to make it an ".app"?

So you get an idea of where Im putting it, Im putting it here:

[image]

so that I can create a new file anywhere.

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20100509134904820) ?

Comment: I keep trying, and i cant seem to figure it out :( Gone through the steps like 3 times and i get errors on the build but it does create a file, but i cant seem to get the key shortcut to work even when i set it...

Answer (score 2):

You should use AppleScript for this instead of bash. I believe you can use AppleScript to both create the file and select the file in the Finder.

To create a file in AppleScript, for example:

```
do shell script "touch /foo.txt"
```

Comment: I read that AppleScript though automates tasks and it will need an application to use to write to it; i.e. it would require opening TextEdit, TextMate, or whatever to actually generate the empty file. Is that true?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should look at Jonas' New Txt File Here script:

http://wisser.me/software/#NewTextFileHere

Answer (score 0):

I have created utility to create file in top window of finder.

Have a look at it.

I have also kept the applescript in article.

http://www.think-1st.com/mac-osx-create-new-file-from-finder-applescript/